Estimation of $H_{n,\frac{1}{2}}$
Question : Determine the value of $\lfloor{ H_{120,\frac{1}{2}} }\rfloor$
My Attempt:
Let $$S=\sum_{j=1}^{120}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} $$
then we can use the following inequality $$\int_{0}^{120}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx>S>\int_{1}^{121}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$
$$2\sqrt{120}>S>20$$
$$22-\Delta>S>20$$
so this approximation was not enough
redoing this for $$S-1=\sum_{j=2}^{120}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}$$
$$\int_{1}^{120}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx>S-1>\int_{2}^{121}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$
$$2\sqrt{120}-1>S>23-2\sqrt{2}$$
$$21-2\Delta>S>20\implies \lfloor{ H_{120,\frac{1}{2}} }\rfloor=20$$
I was asking if there a better method for this which would do this in one go rather than 2 times...

$$ \sim\ 2\sqrt{120} + \zeta\left(1 \over 2\right) + {1 \over 2\sqrt{120}} $$

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With a $\ds{\zeta}$-function identity:
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\sum_{j = 1}^{120}{1 \over \root{j}}} & =
\sum_{j = 1}^{\color{red}{120}}{1 \over j^{\color{red}{1/2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{\color{red}{120}^{1 - \color{red}{1/2}} \over \color{red}{1/2} - 1} + \zeta\pars{\color{red}{1 \over 2}} +
\color{red}{1 \over 2}\int_{\color{red}{120}}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{\color{red}{1/2}\ +\ 1\,}}\,\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & = \
4\root{30} + \zeta\pars{1 \over 2} +
{1 \over 2}\int_{120}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x.
\end{align}
Moreover,
\begin{align}
0 & < {1 \over 2}\int_{120}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x < {1 \over 2}\int_{120}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{3/2}}
\\[5mm] & \implies \color{red}{0 < {1 \over 2}\int_{120}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3/2}}\,\dd x < {1 \over 2\root{30}}}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
& \!\bbx{\underbrace{4\root{30} + \zeta\pars{1 \over 2}}
_{\ds{\approx {\large 20.4485}}}\! <\!
\color{#44f}{\sum_{j = 1}^{120}\!\!{1 \over \root{j}}}\! <\!
\underbrace{4\root{30} + \zeta\pars{1 \over 2} +
{1 \over 2\root{30}}}_{\ds{\approx {\large 20.5398}}}} \\ &
\end{align}

What you could also use is
$$S=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}=H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
which, asymptotically, is
$$H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=2 \sqrt{n}+\zeta
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n}}\Bigg( 1-\frac{1}{12 n}+\frac{1}{192 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)   \Bigg)$$ which gives very tight bounds.
